# Calculation from a formula using tidyverse in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to calculate the following indices using `tidyverse` package in R.

[image]

[image]

[image]

where rm is Monthly rainfall in month m,  m = 1,2,3………12

To achieve this I am using the following code

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(seas) 
library(openxlsx)
library(lubridate)

## get mscdata from "seas" packages
data(mscdata)
dat <- (mksub(mscdata, id=1108447))

Monthly <- dat %>% 
  mutate(Year = year(date),
         Month = month(date),
         Day = day(date)) %>% 
  group_by(Year, Month) %>% 
  summarise(Monthly = sum(precip)) 

Monthly %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise(Rk = sum(Monthly),
            Ck = (1/Rk)*sum(Month*Monthly),
            Zk = sqrt((1/Rk)*sum(Month-Ck)^2*Monthly))
```

The calculation of Rk and Ck is matching with excel calculation. But the values of Zk is not matching. What mistake I am committing?

Comment: What are the expected values of `Zk` ? Do you need `Zk = sqrt((1/Rk)*(Month-Ck)^2*Monthly))` ?

Comment: I want to calculate according to the formula I have provided. The excel values are 4.145470566, 3.81835063, 3.833627623, 3.790112196, 4.185091683. The Rk, Ck, Zk should be one per every year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculated the `sum` too early.

```
library(dplyr)

Monthly %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise(Rk = sum(Monthly),
            Ck = (1/Rk)*sum(Month*Monthly),
            Zk = sqrt((1/Rk)*sum((Month-Ck)^2*Monthly)))

#   Year     Rk     Ck     Zk
#1  1975 1320.1 7.4674 4.1455
#2  1976 1008.3 5.5078 3.8184
#3  1977 1032.3 7.4917 3.8336
#4  1978 1016.8 6.3460 3.7901
#5  1979  986.2 7.4500 4.1851
#6  1980 1418.5 7.2960 3.9661
#7  1981 1459.2 7.0578 3.7275
#8  1982 1260.1 6.0253 4.2520
#9  1983 1489.5 6.2925 4.0069
#...
#...
```

Answer (score 1):

To match your Excel figures, you need to add a pair of parentheses:

```
Monthly %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise(Rk = sum(Monthly),
            Ck = (1/Rk)*sum(Month*Monthly),
            Zk = sqrt((1/Rk)*sum(((Month-Ck)^2)*Monthly)))
```

Comment: Shouldn't the variable Monthly_rain be just Monthly? As @Ronak Shah says, a new question with a bit more to go on would help.